# Replace string in go.sum

Tags: go, import, go-modules

How can i replace a string in go.sum. I use one SDK and it contains a strange import, that import is incorrect, the path of that library was changed to another, and when i do `go mod init` this incorrect import writes to go.sum.

Comment: see go mod edit.

Answer (score 0):

You should not touch go.sum file, make sure your go.mod file is correct and go.sum is adjusted accordingly

Comment: I'm sure that my go.mod is correct. I use library from git, and that library has incorrent import in code

Comment: which library is it? you can check https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive, you can use replace directive at the end of go mod to point to right path.

Comment: replace directive fixes the issues locally but the problem still exists for the consumers of the modules where replace directive is used.